# How can I give message author a role

Tags: python, discord.py

This is able to limit the verify command to a specific channel and checks if the author has the member role. I would like to give them the role upon writing `.verify`, not sure how to do it.

This is the cog

````
from discord.ext import commands
import time
from discord.utils import get

class Bot(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def verify(self, ctx):
        roles = []
        for role in ctx.author.roles:
            roles.append(role)
        isMember = "" in roles
        if ctx.channel.id == 802969634801188884 and isMember == False:

            await ctx.send(f'<@{ctx.author.id}>, you are now verified.')
            time.sleep(3)
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 2)
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.content} is not a command')

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Bot(bot))```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong in your code, and another couple that you could optimize.

```py
async def verify(self, ctx):
    # You don't need the for loop and appending to the `roles` list
    # `ctx.author.roles` already a list of roles
    roles = ctx.author.roles
    # There was another issue, `roles` is now a list of `discord.Role` instances
    # so if you do `"Member" in roles` will always be False, even if the member has the role
    # to fix you can either get the role object, or convert the `roles` list to a list of the role names
    role_names = [role.name for role in roles]
    is_member = "Member" in role_names

    if is_member: # Exiting if the user already has the role
        return await ctx.send("You are already verified") 

    if ctx.channel.id != 802969634801188884: # Exiting as well if it's not the correct channel
        return await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.content} is not a command")

    # Getting the role and adding it
    member_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Member") # I'm guessing the name of the role is `Member`, otherwise change it accordingly
    # You can also use `ctx.guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)` if you want to get the role by ID 
   
    # Adding the roles
    await ctx.author.add_roles(member_role)
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} you are now verified") 
    await asyncio.sleep(3) # `time.sleep` is blocking, you should never use it within your asynchronous code, also remember to `import asyncio`

    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=2)
```

I've tried to put as many comments as possible in the code for you to understand, if you have any doubts feel free to ask in the comments below.

Comment: I was able to understand for the most part, but since I’m coming from having used discord.js, I’m having a difficult time understanding some things. To be more specific, I’m having trouble understanding the ctx object. I got this error upon making the corrections. I didn’t write it out because I’m communicating with my server over my iphone. 

https://discord.com/channels/801978232161304629/802052134597820426/816016432151658556

Comment: That link sadly doesn't work for me. The `ctx` is the `Context` of the command, you can take a look at the docs for more info: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context

Comment: I apologize, I sent the wrong link  https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/802052134597820426/816016431921496154/image0.png

Comment: Did you enable intents? If yes - which?

Comment: Where do I enable them? In the script?

Comment: In the script and the developers portal, take a look at this https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents

Comment: I should mention that you need `intents.members`, `intents.roles` as well as `intents.guilds` and `intents.messages`, easiest way for you would be to enable default intents + privileged member intents

Comment: Not having intents appears to have been the problem. I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad that worked, remember to accept the answer if it helped